# Joomla - Rearrange layout of User Registration and Profile

Tags: joomla

Good day! I would like to ask how will I be able to re-arrange the layout of the user registration and profile page.

I am not describing adding/modifying fields, but to re-arrange them as to how this is rendered in the front-end. I will be using three fieldsets instead of the default one per plug-in, because they are subdivided into three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the "com_users" component's "registration" view.

To override the view, simply add a file in your template.

location:

```
TEMPLATE_NAME/html/EXTENSION_NAME/VIEW_NAME/FILE_NAME.php
```

For your case it must be `TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_users/registration/default.php`

You can read [HERE for more about overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core).

Comment: Is this still applicable with Joomla v.3.3?

Comment: Yes, same for Joomla v.3.3. Can also be done with css but not best solution maybe

Comment: @Ju-chan you can see [HERE](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager#Creating_Overrides) to create overrides from sitemanager (backend). Its easier now.